# Beginner Question: Trouble turning a field with comma separated values into a multi-valued field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

It's my first time using Access, and I have my first of what I assume will be many questions. Yay!

So I imported some data from Excel to a table, including a column with a comma separated tagging system (let's say x, y, z). After some poking around, I went to design view and did the following in the Lookup tab for this "tagging" field:

[image: Lookup tap settings]

What happened: entries with just an x, y, or z tag worked. When I click the drop-down arrow for a given entry, I see x, y, and z as choices with the correct one selected. For entries with multiple tags though, it shows up as a new box to be checked. So if I have x, z in the cell, there's a x, y, z, and x, z selection in the drop-down box.

So my question is, how can I make the boxes with multiple tags work correctly?

Comment: What does "correctly" mean?  Do you want the dropdown to have every combination?  Do you not want a dropdown at all?  Not sure what your desired outcome is.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I do want a dropdown, and I want it to have the correct boxes selected automatically out of the options x, y, and z. If I have x, z in a cell right now, instead of the options of the dropdown box being x, y, z, and x,z with x,z being ticked, I want the "x" and "z" boxes to be ticked.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping to help without having a bunch of knowledge in Access.  I don't currently have it installed or I'd play with it and see if I could solve it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Allow Value List Edits to No?  That might do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use a *many to many* relationship. Generally this is done with a table for the records (like you have now), a table for the comma delimited field and a primary key field with rows for each of the entries (one for x, one for y and one for z) and a third table with nothing but that keys from the other 2 tables.

So, in your join table, you might have a section of 3 rows with the same key on the main table but different entries for the reference table.  This [link](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/create-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-access) explains it reasonably well.